# Google Analytics automaticly generated reports problems

Tags: google-analytics

I got some problems with the automatic generated reports option in Google analytics.

So, i made some reports in my dashboard, personalized them and they are ready to be send to the customer.

I set the dates : 1 Januari - 31 Januari 2014 and compare them with 1 Januari - 31 Januari 2013.

I use the E-mail option in google analytics and use the option automaticly send this report every first of the month too the customer.

But when the customer recieves the reports it doesn't display the dates i setted, but it displays the dates i sended the reports. So i double checked, tested, sended them again and kept facing the same problems.

But when i don't use the automaticly generated option and send them directly to the customerm, the dates are right.

How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't send automated reports with a time range set beyond what Google Analytics has built in - Once, Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly.

[image]

These settings send the report for the previous specified time period.

If you want to send a monthly report with the previous year of data, you are out of luck. Monthly reports only show the previous month and so on for the frequency settings. In short, no rolling data of a user specified time period.

And, no comparison data either like what you are trying to send.

I have to send the previous 90 days of data from a report every month. Since I am unable to do that in Google Analytics with the scheduled reports, I schedule GA to email me the report once a month as a reminder. I then go in and manually create the 90 day report and use GA to email it using the Once frequency.